# Dump a Java HashMap<K,V> to XML and back

Tags: java, xml-serialization

does anyone know of a good library or method of converting the contents of a HashMap to XML and then parsing this to reconstruct the HashMap?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The XStream library is what you want. http://x-stream.github.io/

It has a [HashMap converter](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/collections/MapConverter.html), and a tutorial on [how to use convertors](http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html).

Comment: +1. XStream is the only thing that lets me stomach XML in Java.

Comment: @seanhodges I didn't know this lib, does it have any advantages compared to jaxb?

Comment: @stacker I'm not too experienced with JAXB outside of Axis WS, but my understanding is that it generates Java code based on a schema. XStream lets you use objects based on your own Java classes. Not sure on other factors like performance or J2EE compliance though.

Comment: @stacker From the XStream FAQ: http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#Other_Products_JAXB JAXB and XStream are two completely different approaches

Answer (score 2):

Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)
allows Java you to map Java classes to XML representations. JAXB provides two main features: the ability to marshal  Java objects into XML and tunmarshal XML back into Java object

Where to start? Pick a tutorial from these:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding
- http://jaxb.java.net/
- http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jaxb/

In 15 minutes your done!

Comment: This requires you to define a XSD beforehand which might not fit in with what Aly is working with at all.